# Eclipse C/C++: external library matio "undefined reference to 'Mat_Open'"

Tags: c, matlab, eclipse-cdt, undefined-reference, mat-file

I started experimenting with C/C++ the other day because I needed it for reading level-4 MAT-files without needing to purchase the Matlab editor or compiler. So I found just the library that I needed but I'm not familiar with C or C++ at all so I'm a beginner with those two languages. Anyhow I need to include the 'matio' library. I've tried many things but I've had no luck.

I right clicked on the `C/C++ project > properties > C/C++ General > Paths & Symbols > GNU C` and added the path to the matio library.

I also went to `C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool settings > GCC C Compiler > Includes` and added the path there aswell.

Since I'm not any good with makefiles yet I did not specify my own makefile, instead I chose a executable project.

When I try to build my project it complains about a function called 'Mat_Open' in the matio library. When I hover over it, it says "undefined reference to 'Mat_Open'" the header 'matio.h' seems to work fine but it can't refer to 'Mat_Open' for some reason.

**How do I solve this?**

*EDIT:*

Here is the whole build console output.

```
10:42:52 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Project ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -IC:/matio-1.5.2/src -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o CComponent.o "..\\CComponent.c" 
gcc -Xlinker -lm -o Project.exe CComponent.o -lC:/matio-1.5.2/src 
c:/mingw(x64)/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/matio-1.5.2/src
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

10:42:53 Build Finished (took 330ms)
```

Comment: you are not *linking* against the `matio` library, that's the missing step: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Iqzs.png

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to build it, it says it can't find the directory. Does using backslash or front slash have any significance? If I look in the console the "build syntax/command" seems to have '2' backslashes to sepparate directories.

Comment: @Amro after alot of researching I found out that I needed to add the search path to the library and also the name of the library (matio) and it would add lib to the suffix and it automatically adds "lib" prefix and ".a" (or ".so") suffix. I also didn't install the matio library correct, but with help of you and roybatty I got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily an answer but may be useful for a comparison.

First of all, where did you install it? If your using Linux or Mac OSX you will want to install in the system directories (not sure about Windows).  I use OSX so in my makefile (by the way I [use Qt](http://qt.digia.com)):

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lmatio
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
```

Then of course, in the *.h files of my source I use:

```
#include "matio.h"
```

But I assume you have already tried that?

Comment: Well, I use Windows, I've already included the haeding file 'matio.h' yes. But there wasn't any install-wizard for matio, instead it was a archive that I unziped and I put it into my documents. Should I instead put it one level above my drive directory? (C:/)

Comment: @linus, I have not used this under Windows but is seems like you may not have it installed properly. If you [check this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/matio/discussion/search/?q=windows) you will find some discussion on installation issues.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I installed the msys command-shell and followed the instructions for installing the library. It should be installed correctly now.

Comment: @Linus How do u specify path for HDF5 and zlib in configure file? Can't seem to get it done properly and without them I can't have MAT -v7.3 support.

Comment: @Sndn it has been a very long time since I experimented with this but if I understand you correctly I think you can do something like: `CFLAGS="-Ipath/to/zlib/include -Lpath/to/zlib/lib" ./configure`